# How to stop my model to give prediction for image out of the dataset, with good confidence?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have trained a cnn model for cat, and dog classifier which is giving a good accuracy while predicting cat, and dog. While testing, I gave horse images as input, and my model was able to predict it as dog with 95% confidence. Kindly help me in solving this problem.

Comment: What were you expecting your model to do? We don't evaluate the performance of our model on object classes it hasn't seen before.